# How to handle CFLOCK timeout error?

Tags: coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8 and jQuery.

I am working on a page that does several ajax calls via jQuery. Quite frequently, I see an application timeout error on one of the pages that is called via ajax. I do not get the error on every ajax call. I do not get the error on the same call each time.

From what I understand the error is caused by the different pages each trying to access the same application variable at the the same time. I am not sure what is the best approach to resolve the issue.

The code seems to be setting a two second timeout.  This seems excessive. Should the cflock be set to readonly?  Any other advice?

```
 A timeout occurred while attempting to lock the Application scope.

 The error occurred in E:/INETPUB/WWWROOT/DEV/AVCAT/Application.cfm: line 53
 Called from E:/INETPUB/WWWROOT/DEV/Application.cfm: line 1
 Called from E:/INETPUB/WWWROOT/DEV/Application.cfm: line 53
 Called from E:/INETPUB/WWWROOT/DEV/Application.cfm: line 1

 51 : 
 52 : <!---<cfif NOT IsDefined("application.datasource")>--->
 53 :   <cflock timeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,2,0)#" SCOPE="Application">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `timeout` attribute of the `cflock` tag is expecting seconds.  So if you want a two minute timeout period than the `timeout` attribute should be set to 120.  Like this (and I agree that seems excessive):

```
<cflock timeout="120" SCOPE="Application">
```

The `CreateTimeSpan()` function returns a date/time object.  I'm not sure how your `cflock` is interpreting that value for the timeout.

As far as using an `exclusive` lock versus a `readonly` lock.  If your code is only reading the application scope variables than use a `readonly` lock.  If your code is setting the application scope variables than use an `exclusive` lock.  Using an `exclusive` lock, which you are using by not specifying the `type` attribute, will cause that code to be single threaded.  That may be your issue there.

Comment: `createTimespan(0,0,2,0)` gives the number `0.001388...` - i.e. just under 1.4ms - not much time for a database query!

Comment: Just a note: `createTimespan()` doesn't return a date/time object, it returns a number of days (or parts thereof).  It's just a Double.  `createTimespan(1,0,0,0)` returns 1; `createTimespan(0,12,0,0)` returns 0.5 etc.

Comment: I'd also like to see what it is you're locking. It looks like you're just locking the assignment of `application.datasource`, which is almost certainly just setting a simple string value in a single statement. If so: it does not need to be locked at all. Not since CF5, anyhow.

Comment: This is an existing application developed 10+ years ago. I am fairly confident that the lock is unnecessary. I recommended that it be removed when convenient.  Changing the lock to one second did the trick. No more errors. Thanks!